# OSGI: What is the best approach to wait for a declarative service component to start?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox, declarative-services

I have the following problem:

1: An OSGI bundle A (equinox) is activated, and the activator parses an XML file
2: in the XML file, a declarative service is requested, which is present in another bundle (B)
3: bundle B is not activated yet, so the activator of bundle A needs to wait

I know how to approach this purely in DS, but the parsing needs to be carried out in the activator. Also I do not want to fool around with start levels and the likes. Ideally, I would want to be able to register the service provided by bundle B when needed.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Kees

Comment: AFAIK you can register as BundleListener and see when it is activated

Comment: Oh, and get the work out of the activator.. Not good

Comment: Hi Niels, I know about the activator problem, but currently I am stuck to this problem because of a third party library (and classloading issues).

Comment: Oh yes, this solution would not be better than using the servicelistener

Comment: Depending on the exact issue, it may even be best to skip the whole service dependency and put it all in one bundle.

Comment: Can you explain more about the external dependency and the classloading problem you mention? I think this is your real problem and maybe we can suggest something once we understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSGi services are dynamic by nature and therefore you should never depend on the availability of a service. You need to use some kind of service tracking via a `ServiceTracker` or better, go for the pure DS solution which does all the hard work for you.

Since you indicate that you must parse the XML file, I guess you decided to use some kind of external configuration with services to use. I would suggest to re-consider this type of architecture. You need to write a lot of code while often the same goals can be reached by using a combination of the configuration admin and declarative services/blueprint.

Comment: Well, a change in design was indeed the best solution. I now parse the XML file twice, once (quickly) to determine which services need to be loaded, after which I listen for registered services. If all the services I need are available, I parse the XML file more thoroughly in order to install the services.A bit more work, but a cleaner approach. Thanks